# Download files and/or display pdf through inAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova, pdf, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I successfully added the inAppBrowser Plugin to my Cordova (Ionic) app, but browsing through pages in the link I cannot download files or display PDFs, even though I can in other pages of my app (not in the iAB).

I tried to debug the plugin with adb, but i could not find anything.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I have had issues with the inAppBrowser and PDF's.

The current way I am doing it is by using a document viewer plugin: https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

It isn't ideal as it uses a 2nd app to display the PDF, but it's good enough for now. My aim is to eventually develop my own solution using PDF.js

Comment: I think the question is not well asked or misunderstood. When browsing a page within the iAB plugin, the user can't download anything. So, if there is a pdf in that page, my users can not see them. I can show the page, but if it contains other resources, are impossible to get.

Comment: I get you. I suppose you could use the system browser, so set the target as _system. I'm not sure you can do much to control the behaviour of the plugin.

Comment: That's sad, because I think it's important keep certain *official* resources on the site but I don't want my user leaves the app.

Comment: Can you not directly link to the resources? Rather than browse the page to get a pdf link, directly kink to the pdf?